# Given a generic object (T) and a key of that object (K), can I constrain K to only those keys with a string value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

Very basic example of what I'd like to do:

```
function extractStringValue<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): string {
    return obj[key]; // error: Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'string'
}

// Desired usage

const myObj = { stringKey: "hi", boolKey: false }
const stringVal = extractStringValue(myObj, "stringKey"); // all OK
const stringVal2 = extractStringValue(myObj, "boolKey"); // should raise error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One slight problem with the previous answer is that code completion doesn't work, eg. when you start typing the key name, the editor will not show you the keys.

Also it would be nice when code completion is used, it only shows keys that are strings.

So with some slight modifications you can do ->

```
type StringKeys<T> = Exclude<{
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string ? P : never
}[keyof T], undefined>


function extractStringValue<T extends Record<K, string>, K extends StringKeys<T>>(
  obj: T,
  key: K,
): string {
  return obj[key]; 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcDyAzAKuCAeNAaKSAfFALxQCiAHgMYA2ArgCbYDeAUFJ1ANoAKUASwB2UANbwA9iihoAugC4ZfWVAiVgEIYwQEoAfij9FQiADcIAJzYBfbuJBSZs-PS0QUwiI0JtfoSFAAysAWwgDmcIg4xGSRyOiYOPgIIeE%20-tAAQhIStBAAhkJx0aSw8PEYkElQAEY5eYU%20viiu1MACEiJqIfltwaFCYQBq%20QzYaKrqmtpQAEoQ1BIWjFgwyamDhPgwkxpaOv3hxWiEhAAUHFASNQBWiniX9oprbACUiikDYVDsnBYQwHoFhE1xudngsgA3FAbM1Wu1OrsLL1gNlciMxjhdtMdPNFstVvg6rkCkItrBsfsoGiGkVytFzpdQfdcI94M9We9avVST9Lv9AcCrrdwSAoTDrL5FkIUlAALYgJC3UosKCfI7sqAAcgAFgItfhublIooUKMENBrJC2NLZerBhjSt1kX0NsNRvQIGcFUqbvgtfaIvAta9oQB6MNQRbMKMSOVgPIIkFCWggNU6iQAdx0gciNs6drdGIATE71C7gIcHR6vT7bv7ibRIiHw5GUgJaLRVBYLEsEFKC8AjbRHWRnSiaRjPd7FfXtY3m6HfEA)

If you later want to extract the boolean types, it would make sense making a utility type maybe called `KeysOfType`, so if you say created a function called `extractBooleanValue`, code completion would only show keys that have boolean's in them. etc.

```
type KeysOfType<T, O> = Exclude<{
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends O ? P : never
}[keyof T], undefined>


type StringKeys<T> = KeysOfType<T, string>
type BooleanKeys<T> = KeysOfType<T, boolean>
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcDyAzAKuCAeNAaKSAfFALxQCiAHgMYA2ArgCbYDeAUFJ1ANoAKUASwB2UANbwA9iihoAugC4ZfWVAiVgEIYwQEoAfij9FQiADcIAJzYBfbuJBSZs-PS0QUwiI0JtfoSFAAysAWwgDmcIg4xGSRyOiYOPgIIeE%20-tAAQhIStBAAhkJx0aSw8PEYkElQAEY5eYU%20viiu1MACEiJqIfltwaFCYQBq%20QzYaKrqmtpQAEoQ1BIWjFgwyamDhPgwkxpaOv3hxWiEhAAUHFASNQBWiniX9oprbACUiikDYVDsnBYQwHoFhE1xudngsgA3FAbM1Wu1OrsLL1gNlciMxjhdtMdPNFstVvg6rkCkItrBsfsoGiGkVytFzpdQfdcI94M9We9avVST9Lv9AcCrrdwSAoTDrL5FkIUlAALYgJC3UosKCfI7sqAAcgAFgItfhublIooUKMENBrJC2NLZerBhjSt1kX0NsNRvQIGcFUqbvgtfaIvAta9oQB6MNQRbMKMSOVgPIIkFCWggNU6iQAdx0gciNs6drdGIATE71C7gIcHR6vT7bv7ibRIiHw5GUgJaLRVBYLEsEFKC8AjbRHWRnSiaRjPd7FfXtY3m6HfEA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the playground link is broken. Can you fix please?

Comment: @ShaneCallanan   Yeah, not sure what happened to the TS Link, fixed now.

Comment: I've marked this to be best answer as it covers precisely what I was looking for in my question. Extending from this, is it possible to create an `extractStringOrNumberValue` where keys with either string or number values can be passed in?

Comment: @ShaneCallanan  Yes, `KeysOfType` will also take a union type.  eg. -> `type StringNumberKeys<T> = KeysOfType<T, string | number>`

Answer (score 1):

You should define `T` based on `K`. Since you want `T[K]` to be a string you have to change `T` to extend a `Record<K, string>`, since we don't need anything else this definition is enough:

```
function extractStringValue<T extends Record<K, string>, K extends keyof T & string>(
  obj: T,
  key: K,
): string {
  return obj[key]; 
}
```

Usage:

```
const myObj = { stringKey: 'hi', boolKey: false };
const stringVal = extractStringValue(myObj, 'stringKey'); // all OK
const stringVal2 = extractStringValue(myObj, 'boolKey'); // expected error
```

Comment: Just to note: It's possible to continue using `K extends keyof T` to further constrain the keys that can be passed in, and get IDE autocompletion